# on Amazon EC2 Which metric should I put an alarm on so I don't go over the free tier limit

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I am on the free tier. I dont want go over the free tier limit.

They let you set up an alarm when you go over a certain metric. In the alarm setting you can set the instance to shut down.

I need to know which metric I should watch and stop the instance based on so I dont get charged for EC2 and RDS

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible to be notified when you are *going* to incur a charge. You will be notified when you have crossed a certain threshold. The threshold can be very small (if that helps).

- Go to : [CloudWatch Alarms](https://console.aws.amazon.com/cloudwatch/home?region=us-east-1#alarm:alarmFilter=inOk) *[Select appropriate region]*
- You can either create an alarm on *TotalEstimatedCharge* or *EstimatedCharge* for individual services that you are using (EC2 and RDS in your case)

Once the consumption crosses the threshold you will be notified. But not before that.